# How can I get vaccinated on a Schengen Type D Visa in Poland

Tags: schengen, covid-19

I am a New Zealand citizen living on Poland for the next 6 months (I've been here 6 months already). I would like to get vaccinated, but to the best of my knowledge, I cannot because I'm not working in Poland (and am not allowed to on this visa).

I have a PESEL number, but without Polish medicare (which I can't get because I'm not on a working visa) I am unable to get a referral to be vaccinated (though my age group is eligible).

Some government sites indicate that it should be possible to get a referral with only a PESEL, but I have talked to several GPs and they say they are unable to give it to me without medicare.

Is there an alternative path I can go through to get vaccinated (perhaps applying for a visa with working rights), or should I resign myself to being unable to receive a vaccine until I return home?

Comment: They’ll probably let you do it once domestic demand tapers out. I’d wait for another month.

Comment: Does this help? [Information for foreigners - Szczepienie przeciwko COVID-19 - Portal Gov.pl](https://www.gov.pl/web/szczepimysie/information-for-foreigners) *All foreigners who have not been assigned a PESEL number but hold a residence permit issued for working, studying or staying with their family in Poland may take advantage of Poland’s National Vaccination Programme...* **COVID-19 vaccinations for all foreigners staying in Poland legally are free of charge.**

Comment: @MarkJohnson I'm afraid not. My visa basically counts as an extended tourist visa, so it doesn't fall into any of those categories.

Comment: Since it is free of charge, that sounds strange. They are interested in getting everybody vaccinated that are legally in Poland (which you are).

Comment: Since a **e-referral** can be done based on a passport number, mayby you should just go to a vaccination station and find some who speaks English that could assist you in getting registed in their **e-referral** system.

Comment: Those who are allowed to work likley pay taxes. That's the issue with "free" healthcare.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler Some thing are considered to be in the publich interest. See: [Questions and answers - Coronavirus: information and recommendations - Gov.pl website](https://www.gov.pl/web/coronavirus/questions-and-answers) **If a patient has no insurance and is a foreigner, will he or she be treated in Poland for free?**

Comment: First things first: did you try to [register online for the Covid vaccine with your PESEL and a Polish cellphone number](https://pacjent.erejestracja.ezdrowie.gov.pl/auth)?

Answer (score 1):

Read https://krakowexpats.pl/coronavirus-update/vaccinations-guide-update-30-04-2/ it describes the fast track registration for the health care website if you haven't registered already and from there you can get an appointment. If this fails, go to https://www.gov.pl/web/szczepimysie/rejestracja where it mentions calling 989 and

> Do zapisu wystarczy numer PESEL.

A PESEL number is enough to register. So, just call 989 if you have a Polish phone number, even better. If you don't speak Polish, I would have someone who does help with the call, just in case.

Nowhere does it mention residency as a requirement. From what I am reading, a reference is only needed for people *without* a PESEL.

As a side note, Poland is struggling with vaccinating enough people, chances are they will be glad someone wants the jab.

Answer (score 1):

Germany is offering vaccines for everyone: [Vaccine access](https://www.dw.com/en/covid-germany-allows-everyone-to-sign-up-for-their-vaccination/a-57782978)

Entry restrictions into Germany are listed here: [Entry restrictions](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/einreiseundaufenthalt/EinreiseUndAufenthalt)

Poland is not currently listed as a country of concern by Germany; [Risk areas](https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Transport/Archiv_Risikogebiete/Risikogebiete_aktuell_en.pdf?__blob=publicationFile)

Answer (score -1):

Would you consider a trip to Germany?
It might take a little investigation on where is the best place to go but anecdotal evidence suggests doctors and pharmacies have the vaccines and are looking for patients.

[A link to Irish Times article suggesting Berlin giving vaccines to anyone who asks.](https://www.irishtimes.com/business/health-pharma/germany-makes-j-j-vaccine-available-to-all-adults-1.4560331)

Comment: A highly speculative answer considering that the OP is not a resident of Germany.

Comment: Downvoted, as your evidence is likely to be out of date by now.

Comment: The evidence I presented is a month old, what reason do you have for thinking it to be out of date?